What would the Appsync Javascript QUERY_ITEMS function look like?
This public doc guide hints at an implementation of a neat bit of reusable code

AWS AppSync functions enable you to write common logic that you can reuse across multiple resolvers in your schema. For example, you can have one AWS AppSync function called QUERY_ITEMS that is responsible for querying items from an Amazon DynamoDB data source. For resolvers that you'd like to query items with, simply add the function to the resolver's pipeline and provide the query index to be used. The logic doesn't have to be re-implemented.

I would love to see an implementation of that because it's not obvious to me and I think it would unlock a lot of my understanding about how appsync can be used.

I've implemented a Query for something PK-specific. Is it just using some step to "hardcode" the PK?
export const request = (ctx) => ({
  operation: "Query",
  query: {
    expression: "pk = :pk and (begins_with(sk, :sk))",
    expressionValues: util.dynamodb.toMapValues({
      ":pk": "DataType",
      ":sk": ctx.arguments.sort_path,
    }),
  },
});


I'm not sure I fully understand the question. But all app sync is doing is translating the request into something that the Query API for DynamoDB accepts.
The payload is almost identical for app sync with shortened key names. There's no magic happening.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html
